# NHibernate SysCacheProvider default expiration and cache regions

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way that the default NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider expiry time of 5 minutes can be configured without the use of cache regions?  Is there a hibernate property that can be set from config?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the config file:

```
<property name="cache.default_expiration">seconds</property>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego.  Worked a treat.

Comment: What about fluent nhibernate?

Comment: @Johnny_D `ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SessionFactory().Caching.WithDefaultExpiration(seconds))`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any `config.SessionFactory` section in my ExposeConfiguration delegate.

Comment: @Johnny_D it's an extension method, `using NHibernate.Cfg`